# Ruby - how to find out if a number is within a range with given percentage tolerance?

Tags: ruby

Say I have this case interval:

```
min_value = 500
max_value = 900
```

and I want to find out if a test number, eg. `check_value = 1000` is within 25% around the `min_value` and `max_value`.

In this particular case, the result would be **yes**, because `1000 - 25%` is `750`, which is between `500` to `900`.

Is there a function that does this?

Comment: Tip: `range = (500..900)` and then `range.include?(check_value * 0.75)`

Comment: `(500/1.25..900/0.75).include?(value)` maybe?

Comment: @tadman That doesn't work for the lower bound, e.g. `check_value == 450`. Or even `check_value == 500`, for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a function that does this?

No, there's not an inbuilt method for this; it's a very specific/niche problem.

However, it's fairly straightforward to define a custom method. For example, how about:

```
def in_range_with_tolerance?(check_value:, min_value:, max_value:, tolerance:)
  allowed_range = (min_value / (1 + tolerance) .. max_value / (1 - tolerance))
  allowed_range.include?(check_value)
end

in_range_with_tolerance?(
  check_value: 1000,
  min_value: 500,
  max_value: 900,
  tolerance: 0.25
)
  # => true
```

However, you may wish to think carefully about how this `allowed_range` is actually defined... For example, should the maximum allowed value above actually be 1125, because `900 + 25% == 1125`; or 1200, because `1200 - 25% == 900`? Writing equations with percentages like this is... dubious.

Comment: See also: [`assert_in_epison`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/MiniTest/Assertions/assert_in_epsilon)

Answer (score 0):

Two ranges overlap for a given range A when:

- range B starts within range A,
- range B ends within range A or
- range B starts before range A and ends after range A

Examples:

```
Range A    |-----|
             |-----|  Case 1
         |-----|      Case 2
             |-|      Case 1 + 2
         |---------|  Case 3
```

Looking closer, the rule is: Two ranges overlap when Range B starts before range A ends and range B ends after range A starts.

Imagine range A to be `(min_value..max_value)` and range B `((check_value * 0.75)..(check_value * 1.25))` then you can simplify your condition to:

```
min_value <= (check_value * 1.25) && (check_value * 0.75) <= max_value
```

With the [`Range#overlap?`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Range.html#method-i-overlap-3F) method that was introduced in Ruby 3.3 this can be written as:

```
(min_value..max_value).overlap?(check_value * 0.75..check_value * 1.25)
```